# Meteor Cordova on iOS - App sometimes reloads itself and rolls back to previous update. After restarting it is back to newest update

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, meteor, uiwebview

Something strange is happening to my Meteor Cordova iOS app, and I have no idea how to track it down. I will try to explain in as much detail what I notice.

I am using the Meteor hot code push feature in my iOS Cordova app. I will push the update like normal to Meteor Galaxy.

The app will receive the update and auto refresh itself updating to the newest update. I am able to verify that I am using the newest update. After using the app for few minutes, it will then just refresh itself. After it finishes refreshing the app is back to the old version. If I quit the app, and start it again, it then loads the newest version again. After this point, I can keep using the app and I have not noticed it refresh. Although it still might refresh at times, it is hard to track down why it happens.

My hunch is that it is related to memory. Maybe after a hot code push the Cordova app uses more memory? And once the Cordova apps memory usage is too high iOS auto refreshes the Cordova UIWebView and for some reason, it loads the version prior to the update.

I am not 100% sure that it is related to hot code push either. I have just noticed that using that app after a successful hot code push causes a refresh and rollback after a few minutes of usage. Quit and restart the app, and it is back to the newest update.

If you have any advice on how to track this issue down please let me know!

Comment: Have a look at the logs for a clue. Ideally set up a Safari remote debug session on your app, with `preserve logs` checked, so you can see why it is reverting to the old version. I presume you are pointing to the right server, and have updated the code on the server too

Answer (score 0):

hello should investigate a little how the codepush had the same problem first you should do deploy, then create a new ipa or apk you must have an error in your app. or you can clear the cache in android in ios touch delete the app.

As for the refresh you will always have it, if the app does not have the content that owns the server will perform an update of the content just as a web page does when refreshing, because cordova is a webView.

then if your app presents those problems you make a new deploy, and create apk and ipa.

regards